# how do I print from Termux on Android phone

Tags: android, command-line, printing, termux

I am trying to print from the command line in termux on Android to a printer. The printer is attached to my network by wired Ethernet with a static IP. There are some suggestions here on stack overflow such as:

path-to-file > /dev/tcp/1p_address:9100

I tried this from termux command-line and it printed one line of the file.
Someone else suggested

echo foobar | lp -h ipaddress:9100 -

which to my knowledge would send "foobar" to the printer.  ergo
I tried

cat path_to_file | lp -h ipaddress:9100 -

This prints garbage.

Tried variations of lpr and lp, under cups and was able to communicate with the printer, but printed gibberish.

Tried lpadmin -p but it is forbidden as termux is not rooted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In searching here, I found this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130190/linux-print-directly-to-network-printer-that-is-not-installed).  This helped.  The command line     cat path_to_file | netcat -w 1 printer_IP 9100     printed but printed newlines without carriage returns.  I installed the old dos2unix / unix2dos command, and ran   unix2dos -n path_to_file junk    (to add Carriage returns).  Then piped cat ./junk to the netcat command.  It work, but long lines ran off the page.  used python line breaks to break up long lines -success